# Is There Some Plug-In About Altitude on Android App

Tags: android, performance, altitude

Now I am developing an android, and it includes these functions: get GPS, Altitude and speed, I know how to get GPS, but I have no idea about how to get Altitude and speed, who knows some plug-in can get both Altitude and speed, just tell me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`LocationManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) provides access to `Location` data with altitude and speed for location providers that offer it, like `GPS_PROVIDER`.